# Demostrate that: $ \tau(n)\varphi(n) ≥ n$

Tags: number-theory

Either $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$ the factorization prime of $n>1$. Demostrate:

$$ \tau(n)\varphi(n) ≥ n$$

Help me with this excersices, $\tau(n)$ is tao, $\varphi(n)$ is Euler

### Suggestion:

Show that: $\tau(n)\varphi(n) ≥ 2^r n\left(\dfrac 1 2\right)^r$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\tau(n)\phi(n)}{n} = (k_1+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k_r+1)\prod_{j=1}^{r}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)$$
but for any $j\in[1,r]$, we have:
$$ (k_i+1)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\geq 2\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)=1.$$

Comment: The "reason" this is true is that for $\phi(n)/n$ to be small, then $n$ has to have lots of prime factors, but then $\tau(n)$ is large.